# XCode Build Parse Error 'Unexpected @ in Program'

Tags: xcode, parsing, animation, build

I'm following a tutorial for creating an animation using Xcode Version 4.5.2 in Mountain Lion 10.8.2.  When trying to build the code below, I get a ***Parse Error Unexpected '@' in program*** showing up for the '***hopAnimation=***' line.  While searching, I have found examples that build simple animations in a different way, but nothing that seems to address this particular problem.  I'm a noob to XCode programming and if anyone could help me correct the syntax, I would highly appreciate it.  I would also like to thank all the contributors to stackflow for making this such a valuable resource.  Searching for the answers to most of my prior questions always seemed to have you guys at the top of the results list.

```
    ViewController.m
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        // load all the frames of our animation into an array
        NSArray *hopAnimation;
        hopAnimation=[[NSArray alloc] arrayWithObjects:
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-1.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-2.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-3.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-4.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-5.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-6.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-7.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-8.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-9.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-10.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-11.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-12.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-13.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-14.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-15.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-16.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-17.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-18.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-19.png”],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@”frame-20.png”],nil];

        self.bunnyView1.animationImages=hopAnimation;
        self.bunnyView2.animationImages=hopAnimation;
        self.bunnyView3.animationImages=hopAnimation;
        self.bunnyView4.animationImages=hopAnimation;
        self.bunnyView5.animationImages=hopAnimation;
        self.bunnyView1.animationDuration=1;
        self.bunnyView2.animationDuration=1;
        self.bunnyView3.animationDuration=1;
        self.bunnyView4.animationDuration=1;
        self.bunnyView5.animationDuration=1;
       [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no init method called `arrayWithObjects`. There is `initWithObjects`, or simply `[NSArray arrayWithObjects]` (without alloc), but this will not work. Also, your quotes are the "smart quotes", the curly ones. I don't know if it's like that in Xcode, but you'll probably have to use straight quotes (") to make that work, too.

Comment: OMFG....it was the curly quotes rather than the straight quotes.  That's what I get for being a lazy SoB and doing a 'cut and paste' from the code example.  Thank you for pointing out the obvious to anyone but me.  :)~